# Darkening the terminal's window-shadow (or changing its color)

Tags: 14.04, command-line, unity, gnome-terminal

I recently darkened my terminal's background (easier on the eyes!), but now, when I put multiple terminals on top of one another, they kind of meld together.

Previously, the shadow was what made it easy to differentiate them. How can I, say, make the shadow a nice crimson (because I'm edgy) and darken it so it'll be visible when terminals are laid over one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify the `unity.css` file of the theme. [Here](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/Flattiance/blob/332ae9ce89cfa503e49932891e96ef459739fbcb/Flattiance/gtk-3.0/apps/unity.css#L3-L20) is an example from a theme I modified.

```
UnityDecoration {
    -UnityDecoration-extents: 28px 0 0 0;
    -UnityDecoration-input-extents: 10px;

    -UnityDecoration-shadow-offset-x: 0px;
    -UnityDecoration-shadow-offset-y: 3px;
    -UnityDecoration-active-shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -UnityDecoration-active-shadow-radius: 10px;
    -UnityDecoration-inactive-shadow-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -UnityDecoration-inactive-shadow-radius: 5px;

    -UnityDecoration-glow-size: 10px;
    -UnityDecoration-glow-color: rgb(221, 72, 20);

    -UnityDecoration-title-indent: 10px;
    -UnityDecoration-title-fade: 35px;
    -UnityDecoration-title-alignment: 0.0;
}
```

There you see the `shaddow` properties which are pretty human readable, at least developer readable. Everybody should know CSS. `:-)`